# A local parameter named 'column' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Tags: c#, sql

Hey I'm trying to make a connection to a SQL server in a Visual Studio application(which was successful so far) and to get all the contents of a Table but for some reason the code below won't work. It says:

> A local parameter named 'column' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Code :

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            Dictionary<string, string> column;
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT username, message FROM dbo.[Table];";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, cnn);

            try
            {
                cnn.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    column = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                    column["username"] = reader["username"].ToString();
                    column["message"] = reader["message"].ToString();

                    rows.Add(column);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                cnn.Close();
            }
            foreach (Dictionary<string, string> column in rows)
            {
                Console.Write(column["message"]);
                Console.Write(column["username"]);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

Comment: You can't use the same name for `Dictionary<string, string> column;` and `foreach (Dictionary<string, string> column in rows)` : just rename for example the first to `columns` because it is a collection of columns, and the last `row` because this item is comes from the collection `rows`, therefore it will be clean.

Comment: Side note: I hope you are disposing your connection and reader objects with `using` and not caching them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0136) is pretty clear - you have a local variable named `column` and then trying to declare a loop variable with the same name in `foreach`. Try changing the loop to something like:

```cs
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> row in rows)            
{
    Console.Write(row["message"]);
    Console.Write(row["username"]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

or move `Dictionary<string, string> column;` inside the while loop (personally I dont's see any need to declare it in the outer scope):

```cs
while (reader.Read())
{
    Dictionary<string, string> column = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // can use var here or = new() for latest C# version

    column["username"] = reader["username"].ToString();
    column["message"] = reader["message"].ToString();

    rows.Add(column);
}
```

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#scopes) part of language specification can be helpful, though not very easy, or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/csharp-code-blocks/) tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

just rename the iteration variable 'column' of this line:

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> column in rows)
```

to anything else and in the loop reference it.